# How to set headers for forwarded request

Tags: http-headers, laravel-5

My controller's methods require a header to be set, e.g. `X-Authorization`. After a new object has been created (`store` action), I do a forward to show the newly created object (`show` action):

```
$request = Request::create(route('api.v1.b.show', ['booking' => 4]), 'GET');
Request::replace($request->input());
return Route::dispatch($request);
```

The forwarding works ok if I disable the authorization check, but it fails otherwise. ie. the header has gone. I would like to copy the request header, which I can get with `Request::header('X-Authorization')` into the forwarded request. Is it possible?

I have tried without success to do `$request->header('X-Authorization', 'xxxxx')`. Also tried PHP's `header()` before the dispatch and didn't work.

Any ideas? Cheers

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Ok, i think you need to set the headers like so:

```
$request = Request::create(route('api.v1.b.show', ['booking' => 4]), 'GET');
$request->headers->set('X-Authorization', 'xxxxx');
```

That is the answer to your question.

My question is: Where can we set this headers for every api request(forwarding)? Because i personally have 5 headers to set with the request and i don't want to repeat myself.

Comment: This works. I couldn't test it before. Hoping to see a way to copy all the headers. Cheers

Comment: What if I want to set multiple headers at once?

Comment: @Husam Please check my answer to set multiple headers at once [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60040477/1711723)

Comment: you can make custom middleware and add your headers in handle function and then add this middleware to your api route.

Comment: create method syntax :         create(string $uri, string $method = 'GET', array $parameters = [], array $cookies = [], array $files = [], array $server = [], $content = null); You can add headers array as $server parameter

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone might need this i just wanted to post it could help someone

```
       $request =new Request();
       $request->headers->set('Authorization', {{your_key_here}});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// From @musicvicious answer
$request = Request::create(route('api.v1.b.show', ['booking' => 4]), 'GET');
```

If you want to set multiple headers at a time, you can pass more arguments to `Request::create()`

```
/**
 * Creates a Request based on a given URI and configuration.
 *
 * The information contained in the URI always take precedence
 * over the other information (server and parameters).
 *
 * @param string $uri        The URI
 * @param string $method     The HTTP method
 * @param array  $parameters The query (GET) or request (POST) parameters
 * @param array  $cookies    The request cookies ($_COOKIE)
 * @param array  $files      The request files ($_FILES)
 * @param array  $server     The server parameters ($_SERVER)
 * @param string $content    The raw body data
 *
 * @return static
 */
```

Pass your headers starting with 'HTTP_' in `$server` argument.

```
$server = [
    'HTTP_YOUR_HEADER_NAME_1' => 'Value 1',
    'HTTP_YOUR_HEADER_NAME_2' => 'Value 2',
];
```

Your request will have header like below

```
your-header-name-1: Value 1;
your-header-name-2: Value 2;
```