# How to append Authorization Header in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, token, jwt

I'd like to append `Authorization: Bearer {yourtokenhere}` in my Laravel. If in 
Postman I put the Authorization on Headers Tab and give token value manually by writing `Bearer {token}` so I can protect specific route, but how to do this in Laravel source code? What should I do in my controller or should I add another method on Middleware or Kernel or somewhere else?
This is because I got `{"error":"token_not_provided"}` every accessing a route that protected with `jwt.auth middleware`.

This is my protected route which is give me `{"error":"token_not_provided"}`:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth']], function(){
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'AppController@dashboard');
});
```

And this is my signin method inside AuthController :

```
  public function signin(Request $request)
  {
    $this->validate($request, [
      'username' => 'required',
      'password' => 'required'
    ]);
    // grab credentials from the request
    $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');
    try {
        // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json([
              'error' => 'Invalid Credentials, username and password dismatches. Or username may not registered.',
              'status' => '401'
            ], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }

    return response()->json([
      'user_id' => $request->user()->id,
      'token'   => $token
    ]);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this like

`$request = Request::create(route('abc', 'GET');
$request->headers->set('X-Authorization', 'xxxxx');`

for more info you can follow this stackoverflow answer
[How to set headers for forwarded request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32869645/how-to-set-headers-for-forwarded-request)

if you using jwt you can even pass your token in url too
like `www.example.com/post?token=kjdhfkjsffghrueih`

and like you said , you need this in `AuthAcontroller` then you have to set this in client side.
first store that token in localstorage and set that token to http call(via ajax or axios i guess) from localstorage and then send request to laravel.

for accessing in ajax call you can use below code

`headerParams = {'Authorization':'bearer t-7614f875-8423-4f20-a674-d7cf3096290e'}; //token form localstorage`

and then use it in ajax like

`type: 'get',
 url: 'https://api.sandbox.slcedu.org/api/rest/v1/students/test1',
 headers: headerParams,`

or if you using axios you can set this by

`axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('SecurityKey');`

Comment: where I should set this? In my signin on AuthController or where?

Comment: why uh need to set in authcontroller it shoud be set in client side, if you are using this route from android then set ti from android or if you are using some ajax calls like `axios` or `jQuery`  it can be set there

Comment: thanks it works by trying this : `www.example.com/post?token=kjdhfkjsffghrueih`, but how can I every accessing route always put  `?token=[myToken]` automatically?

Comment: And should I store the token into session/cookie or may localStorage if using Ajax? Because in my last project (MEAN Stack) I did to save the token and user data in localStorage.

Comment: @Manchesteriyah Sorry for late reply , but yes you are right you have to set token in localstorage with name like 'securityKey` or `AccessKey` or anything sutiable for you. and you can set your header in ajax like `headerParams = {'Authorization':'bearer t-7614f875-8423-4f20-a674-d7cf3096290e'};` and then use that variable in ajax like `type: 'get',headers: headerParams,`

Comment: if its answer help you , you can mark it for another user , who have similer problem. and i update my answer for better understanding